Is Blender's baking process (and by extension its FBX Exporter) broken?
I am not animating with NLAs.  This is just a standard animation of a game character rig.
When I go to Pose > Animation > Bake Action
then select:
Only selected bones
Pose
Location, Rotation, Scale
And hit OK, I then see that the baking process has seriously messed with my curves. (See image).
The same happens when I try to Export to an FBX.  The baking process will corrupt my curves.
I'd be delighted to know if I was doing something wrong, because I could change it, but I'm worried that Blender is unable to bake with 1:1 accuracy.
(I'm using Blender 4.2).

To follow-up, it seems like Euler Rotations are where it falls down the hardest.  This is a perfect example of this:

As a professional animator, I need to have clear rotation values, so I'm reliant on Euler as a rotation method.  It is impossible to animate properly with Quaternian rotations because animating along one axis keys ALL axes, and that's problematic for animating with any kind of control.
So, when baking keys is problematic for Euler rotations, that an ACTUAL problem.
There are rough workarounds for this, namely using Rigify to convert rotations to Quaternian, but this only works half the time.
This is important because once the animations are done, the keys will be baked during the FBX Export process, which I assume uses the same baking method as the main program.  These FBXs have exported with wonkier and wonkier rotations the larger the animation file gets.
I absolutely love Blender, but what's to be done about the baking process that is, to me at least, clearly broken?
Update:
The reason why converting to Quaternian only works half the time is because it will corrupt the curve if there isn't enough keys on a curve to prevent the conversion process from taking the shortest path to the next key. (Eg. Rather than go all the way around from 0 degree to 360 degrees, a quaternian rotation would interpret that as not rotating at all).
This means an animator will have to manually (not by baking) insert more keys in a curve to prevent the conversion process from doing that.  Ask any animator and this is what we try to avoid doing.

It's explained better in this video here: Dropbox link
Surely, this process can be improved.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

That looks like the values are being accumulated. I believe that’s a checkbox somewhere…

Would you like to share a simplified version of your file, I couldn't reproduce the issue as it looks like on your screenshot.

Hi Leander, I've created a bug report for this issue, which has a simplified .blend file that you can download.  Please go to:  https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/126976
